# Integrating TFS 2012 with SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

Does anyone have a detailed write up on integrating Team Foundation Server 2012 (on premise) with SharePoint 2013 (on premise), specifically where SP is setup with separate Web and App Servers.

1. My understanding is that the TFS extensions need to be setup on the Web and App Server but installation on the Web Server is failing.
2. When configuring the SP web app on the TFS Server, do we point it to the Web Server or App Server?

Comment: What is the nature of the failure?

Comment: I think we figured it out, apparently TFS Extensions can only be installed on a Web Application hosted on Port 80.